# How do I get database data using firebase/nuxtjs

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nuxt.js

I don't know how to get the data via

```
this.$fire.database
```

I've read the firebase docs but in firebase/nuxtJs different it becomes easier
https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/

In firebase docs

```
import { getDatabase, ref, onValue} from "firebase/database";

const db = getDatabase();
const starCountRef = ref(db, 'posts/' + postId + '/starCount');
onValue(starCountRef, (snapshot) => {
  const data = snapshot.val();
  updateStarCount(postElement, data);
});
```

But when I call onValue, it doesn't find it

```
this.$fire.database.onValue()
```

nuxt.config.js file

```
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    [
      '@nuxtjs/firebase',
      {
        config: {
          apiKey: "<private data>",
          authDomain: "<private data>",
          projectId: "<private data>",
          storageBucket: "<private data>",
          messagingSenderId: "<private data>",
          appId: "<private data>"
        },
        services: {
          auth: true, // Just as example. Can be any other service.
          database: {
            emulatorPort: 3000,
            emulatorHost: 'localhost',
          }
        },
      }
    ]
  ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply

```
this.$fire.database.ref('name').on("value", function(e) {
  console.log(e.val())
})
```

**simple explanation :**

```
ref("name")
```

in Realtime Database :
[image]

Whenever the value is changed, the function will run